# How can I deploy multi wordpress in kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, kubernetes

I try to deploy wordpress/mysql in kubernetes.
I want mysql and wordpress to use different volumes. I'm trying to write nfs for wordpress and hostpath for mysql.

But wordpress and mysql are not connected. I don't know why. I'd appreciate your help.

here's my code:
Mysql.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3306
      protocol: TCP
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: qwer1234
    volumeMounts:
      - name: mysql-volume
        mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumes:
      - name: mysql-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-svc
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeName: mysql-pv
​
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /vol/mysql
```

---

wordpress.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: wordpress
        name: wordpress
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: mysql:3306
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          value: P@ssw0rd
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /nfs-volume/html
          name: wordpress-pv
        ports:
          - protocol: TCP
            containerPort: 80
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-pv
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wordpress-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: wordpress-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeName: wordpress-pv
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: wordpress-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.201.11
    path: /nfs-volume
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-svc
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

Comment: What speaks against https://www.presslabs.com/ ? It's a nice operator/ui to manage your installations. No need for difficult and custom installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have provided the port number at last in environment variable

please try with out it

```
env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: mysql:3306
```

instead use this

```
env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: MySQL
```

you can check the example at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

if you read the documentation of Docker image they are also providing the host name without the port as value.

also in Wordpress environment you have to pass the MySQL password which you are passing wrong

```
- name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          value: P@ssw0rd
```

instead it should be

```
- name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          value: qwer1234
```

Comment: hello thank you for your advice.
but it still doesnt work.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11nGxyZ8W9M9ePev1ewhTuad9T1R1ffyD/view?usp=sharing

I try to connect 192.168.201.200:30687 this ip. but It doesnt show anything..

Comment: ah, I fixed wordpress password and mysql password. they are same now.

Comment: Trying directly opening the load balancer IP without port check on port 80 once

Comment: It shows me "Error establishing a database connection"
So I check the log about mysql. 
[Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'10.233.120.57' (using password: NO)
```
And I use 'kubectl describe mysql' command to see what happend
Maybe  
```
 /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-swz8d (ro)
Volumes:
  mysql-volume:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
  default-token-swz8d:
    Type:        Secret 
    SecretName:  default-token-swz8d

Isn't the service account the cause?

Comment: OK!!!! I did it!!!!!!!!!!!

I guess it causes from nfs filesystem.
I added no_root_squash on this
sudo vi /etc/exports
/nfs-volume *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
sudo mkdir /nfs-volume
sudo chmod -R 777 /nfs-volume
sudo exportfs -arv

and success! Thankyou Harsh~!